# IOS ABPerson is Member of ABGroup

Tags: iphone, addressbook

Is there a fast way in the Address Book framework on the iOS platform to determine which groups a particular address book record belongs too?  I have been slogging through the docs and it looks like the answer is no.

I need to quickly slap up a list of groups and a checkmark to indicate membership for a particular address book entry.  Right now it looks like I need to build the list of groups and group members then search it.  Since group membership can be changed in multiple places, I have no easy way of persisting the information between launches and ensuring its still valid.

Thanks for any help.

Rich

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you are right. In iOS you can't fast and easy get group membership of contact.
you can iterate groups arrays only every time :(

Comment: Sigh i was afraid of that.   At least if the abgroup record had a last modified property i could use that to trigger a refresh.  Thanks for confirming my fears :)